# Ordering an integer array - Lowest to Highest - No Tools Challenge

Tags: code-golf

**Here's the challenge:**

Order an Array from the Lowest to the Highest digit from a number, which is conveniently represented in an array. The trick here is that you cannot use any array methods, nor other sorts of loopholes. You have to stick to the basics (Arrays, Mathematical Operators /not Math Class/, no recursion. You can use any variable type of your chosing (eg: String, int), and evidently repetitive cicles, you can't however use "advanced" expressions, such as ArrayList or ParseInt for Java)

For an user input of `2014`, the output should be `0124` Yes, the 0 must be represented

**Scoring Method**

Simply a codegolf challenge, shortest code wins.

**Origin of the challenge:**

I've been reading quite a bit of codegolf for a while, and decided to create a challenge based on an issue that I had with java to order the digits of a number. I did manage to get a solution, but I wasn't quite pleased with it (it took a significant ammount of bytes which I wanted to avoid), I am interested in creative, short awnsers to counter my own =)

Comment: Just to clarify, the program must be valid for any integer, 2014 was an example.

Comment: And evidently, any downvote without a plight explanation is the same as flipping me the finger, which I find rude.

Comment: How is the array defined?  Is it user input or defined in the program, and if so, how do you want to count the bytes in `int[] array = {INSERT AN UNKNOWN NUMBER OF BYTES HERE}`?

Comment: Can't speak for anyone else, but in my opinion, as [code-golf sorting challenges](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=[code-golf]+sort+is%3Aq) go this is *really* boring. And thinking that recursion is not "basic" suggests that you may be just beginning to program; believe me, it is on the same level of the basic tool box as looping. Moreover, the limitations and scoring modifiers make it look like you are trying to use CodeGolf SE as a mechanical turk willing to do your homework. And people can react badly to that impression no matter the truth or falsity of it.

Comment: Scoring item 1 and 2 are unnecessary. For 3 and 4, I highly doubt any golfed submission will reach over 500 bytes. 5 seems strange and put in there for no reason, and 6 makes very little sense at all - why does Java get priority over, say, C++? 7 just begs for someone to answer "foobarbaz in Perl, it doesn't work but I still get the first submission bonus" or something. Furthermore, typically challenges here do not have deadlines.

Comment: I'm not a professsional programmer, but I'm not either a begginer (I do know how to work with, and prefer to use recursion). This was however an issue I had when starting out. Regarding kitcar2000's comment, I made it that way so it would be a four digit example, with a number that contained a 0 (to explain should it occur). As per "asking others to do my homework", they are partially correct, this was once part of my homework, and that's why I'm interested in looking at solutions different from mine (And mine was in java, hence why that scoring bonus)

Comment: @Doorknob What would you recommend as a scoring method?

Comment: A more ideal method would be plain code-golf: shortest code wins. You may also want to clarify what "the basics" are - that's extremely underspecified at the moment.

Comment: I've edited the Question, what do you think of it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. You say it's about sorting an integer array, and then give an example where you sort the digits of a single decimal integer. You prohibit the use of "array methods" but allow the use of arrays. Also, how could the use of string variables possibly help with the task of sorting an array of integers? And what is an "evidently repetitive cicle"?

Comment: Oh screw this, I was about to hit the submit button with a SleepSort and it was closed.

Comment: The original proposition was a sole number, which was then turned into an array composed of the digits (2014 -> 2,0,1,4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/), without explicit recursion :-P

```
(define Y (lambda (f) ((lambda (x) (x x)) (lambda (x) (lambda (y) ((f (x x)) y))))))
(define a (Y (lambda (f) (lambda (c) (cond ((null? c) c)
                                           ((null? (cdr c)) c)
                                           ((> (car c) (cadr c))
                                            (f (cons (cadr c) (cons (car c) (cddr c)))))
                                           (#t (cons (car c) (f (cdr c)))))))))
(define b (Y (lambda (f) (lambda (c) (let ((s (a c))) (if (equal? s c) c (f s)))))))
```

Call:

```
(b '(2 0 1 4))
```

where

- `Y` is the [Y-Combinator](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html)
- `a` is one iteration of Bubble Sort
- `b` is the bubble sort algorithm

Comment: Guess I can't really accept other awnsers